# Нужно найти пифагоровы тройки через рекурсивную функцию

Tags: c++

Понял, как сделать через обычную функцию, но нужно сделать через рекурсию. Пользователь задает значение, до которого нужно найти все пифагоровы тройки(чтобы ни одна из сторон не превышала заданное значение)

```
void pifagor(int pif){
    for (int x = 1; x < pif; x++){
        for (int y = 1; y <pif; y++){
            for (int z = 1; z < pif; z++){
                if (x * x + y * y == z * z ) {
                    cout << "{ " << x << ";" << y << ";" << z << "}" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
int pif;
cin >> pif;
pifagor(pif);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Одну? Все бесконечное количество? Может, дадите точное условие задачи?...

Comment: Прошу прощения, пользователь задает значение, до которого нужно найти все пифагоровы тройки(чтобы ни одна из сторон не превышала заданное значение).

Comment: Ну, очевидно, что это требование относится только к гипотенузе :)

Comment: Третий цикл нужен только если очень холодно. Двух достаточно

Comment: Дело в том, что это нужно сделать с рекурсией функции, а как это сделать в данной задаче я не знаю.
По поводу гипотенузы это понятно, но через неё  у меня в рекурсию выйти не получилось.

Comment: Да даже непонятно, как эту сову-рекурсию на этот глобус натянуть... Без рекурсии, кстати, лучше так: https://ideone.com/CISYnW

Comment: Да, там код лучше будет, т.к. в моем будут повторы троек и также присутствовать "не примитивные тройки". Попробую натянуть рекурсию на код, который вы скинули. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать следующее

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int pifagor(const int limit, int bound, int n)
{
    if (bound != 0 && bound <= limit)
    {
        int m = n!=1? bound: pifagor(limit, --bound, n);

        if (n < m)
        {
            if (m*m+n*n <= limit)
            {
                std::cout << m*m-n*n << " " 
                          << 2*m*n   << " " 
                          << m*m+n*n << std::endl;
            }

            pifagor(limit, m, ++n);
        }
    }

    return ++bound;
}
```

Comment: запуск из main соответственно ```pifagor(n, n, 1);``` где ```n``` ваш порог